# how to implement vue-routing based on first time visit and already visited

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have to make navigation based on certain criteria in vuejs app with vue-routing.Basically the app is shortening the given urls.

1).If the user visits the page first time, i need to display home page
2). If already user has visited, then it should render page which display the shorturls created by the user.

Please anyone help

Comment: You can use cookie for this, so first time when I visit your page you will save alreadyVisited: true and next time you will check if alreadyVisited true

Comment: I have implemented cookies,but the thing is how to render the components based on this ?

Comment: In that case you can use dynamic component, so:

<component :is="loadComponent"></component>

and loadComponent is computed property, where you will check if user have already visited your page or not, you will return string (name of your component)

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic component

```
<component :is="loadMyComponent"/>

loadMyComponent () {
  let visited = false
  // check if users visited your page, you can use cookie
  return visited ? 'first-component' : 'second-component'
}
```